# redirection ">" can take 2 arguments?

Tags: linux, shell, redirect

`echo "output of echo" > f1.txt what is this`

As a result, f1.txt was created(it did not exist earlier), and this is the content of f1.txt

```
cat f1.txt
output of echo what is this
```

It seems that ">" can take two arguments, the first argument is the file name, and the second is the input for the file.

but when I changed echo to cat, it doesn't work

````
cat < a.txt > f1.txt ohlala
cat: ohlala: No such file or directory```





Please explain how this line - "echo "output of echo" > f1.txt what is this" works exactly. I can't find the > syntax for this kind.
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output redirection doesn't have to be the *last* pair of words of the command; they can occur any time after the command name (and in the case of a simple command, even *before* the command name.

What the shell does is first scan the entire command looking for `> <word>`, then processes that as an output redirection *before* running the command with the remaining words as the arguments. All of the following are equivalent:

- `> f1.txt echo "output of echo" what is this`
- `echo > f1.txt "output of echo" what is this`
- `echo "output of echo" > f1.txt what is this`
- `echo "output of echo" what > f1.txt is this`
- `echo "output of echo" what is > f1.txt this`
- `echo "output of echo" what is this > f1.txt`

because `> f1.txt` is removed, in each case leaving behind

```
echo "output of echo" what is this
```

as the command to actually execute, namely `echo` with 4 arguments.

`>` takes *one* "argument"; the shell uses it to open a file for writing and passes that file descriptor to the command (when it finally runs) to use as standard output. In other words, no command is passed to `>`, but rather whatever `>` produces is passed to the *process* that executes the command.

Your `cat` command, after removing the input and output redirections, is `cat ohlala`, and there is no *file* named `ohlala` for `cat` to open. (It's not a *shell* error, but a `cat` error.)